# Refresh the page after sound is done playing in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Stumped, I want to have a paper crumple sound play when I click the button to clear to localstorage data, but have to refresh the page after the localstorage data is cleared to update the changes, and the refresh is not allowing the sound effect to play. So I want it to wait till the sound effect finishes and then trigger the refresh. Thanks!

My HTML:

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="paper_crumple.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<section class="note">

    <h3 id="clear">Clear Note</h3>
    <h1 id="title" contenteditable="true">Note Title</h1>
    <h2 id="date" contenteditable="true">Date Written</h2>
    <p id="note" contenteditable="true">Hello! Click on the note card and start editing!
        <br>
        <br>
        Try refreshing the page, notice that your content stays.
        <br>
        Try closing your browser, shutting your computer off, and then opening it up again.
        <br>It still stays! This is all thanks to the html5 localstorage api.
        <br>
        <br>
        Note that the data will not sync between different browsers, computers, or any other devices such as your mobile phone.
        <br>
        <br>
        This note is responsive! Try adjusting your window size and see how the width adjusts.
        <br>
        Also note that when you get to mobile width, the note adjusts to best take use of the limited space.
        <br>
        <br>
        Tips: You can press ctrl+b for <b>bold</b> text. Similarly you can do the same thing but for <u>underlined</u> or <i>italic text</i>.</p>

</section>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
    <script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      var title = document.getElementById('title');

      $(title).blur(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('title', this.innerHTML);
      });

      // when the page loads
      if ( localStorage.getItem('title') ) {
        title.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('title'); 
      }

      // to reset
      // localStorage.clear();

    });

    $(function() {

      var date = document.getElementById('date');

      $(date).blur(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('date', this.innerHTML);
      });

      // when the page loads
      if ( localStorage.getItem('date') ) {
        date.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('date'); 
      }

      // to reset
      // localStorage.clear();

    });

    $(function() {

      var note = document.getElementById('note');

      $(note).blur(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('note', this.innerHTML);
      });

      // when the page loads
      if ( localStorage.getItem('note') ) {
        note.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('note'); 
      }

      // to reset
      // localStorage.clear();

    });

    window.onload = function() {
        var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
        var myaudio = new Audio('paper_crumple.mp3');
        clear.onclick = function() {
            myaudio.play()
            localStorage.clear()    
            // window.location.reload()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting an answer to this problem, I finally got it to work so I figured I'd share my solution with the community.

Just gave the link an ID and made the content of the href equal to: javascript:void(0);

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clear">Clear Note</a>
```

Then I just put this into  file script.js file:

```
window.onload = function() {

var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'paper_crumple.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
    audioElement.setAttribute('onended', 'window.location.reload()');

function playAudio() {
    audioElement.load;
    audioElement.play();
};

clear.onclick = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    playAudio();
    $("#wrapper").addClass("fadeOutDown");
};

};
```

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try using ended event http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#event-media-ended

```
clear.onclick = function() {
    myaudio.play()
    localStorage.clear()    
    myaudio.onended = function () {
        window.location.reload()
    }
}
```

This is basically saying - "After finished playing sound - reload page"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Its definitely an issue with the .oneended part, the music will play fine otherwise. Intresting bit is that if I put the onended as a value in the audio tag it will work, but doesn't seem to work when the audio is called using the button. Thanks again.